DataHub + Apache NiFi
I connected my Apache NiFi to the DataHub
Succeeded ingestion
Recipe, but I can't see my data stream and all the components /process groups.
Empty data flow
Datahub shows only empty NiFi pipeline.
Please tell me what's the matter?
I want to see my data flow in the form of Datahub's lineage
